# Designing URIs for RESTful Web Services

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

http://www.filesspecialtours.com/ER.png

---

To get "agrupaciones" I do:

GET /agrupaciones/

To get "asociados" I do:

GET /agrupaciones/asociados/

How to do to obtains the result of cross two resources?

agrupaciones.*, asociados.*

Any common method for to do it?

Comment: Is "agrupaciones" not a collection of "asociados"? If not they you probably would not do /agrupaciones/asociados/

Comment: The first line it's a link to E/R diagram. I´ts show the relations between two tables. Relation 1-N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do because my Spanish isn't great, but if you want all "asociados" returned then return them in the "agrupaciones" resource. For example

```
GET /agrupaciones

{
    nombre: "Movie Club",
    asociados [
        {
            url: "/agrupaciones/asociados/1"
            nombre: "Bob",
            archivo_esp: "blah",
            archivo_por: "blah blah",
            ...
        },
        {
            url: "/agrupaciones/asociados/2"
            nombre: "Sally",
            archivo_esp: "blah2",
            archivo_por: "blah2 blah2",
            ...
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

If you don't want to return that much data in one go you can just use the URL

```
GET /agrupaciones

{
    nombre: "Movie Club",
    asociados [
        {
            url: "/agrupaciones/asociados/1"
            nombre: "Bob",
        },
        {
            url: "/agrupaciones/asociados/2"
            nombre: "Sally",
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

and then the client can follow the URL if they want further information about the member.